# Column spacing list in tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes

I have the following code:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \matrix [draw,column sep={1mm, 4cm},nodes=draw]
  {
    \node(a) {123}; & \node (b) {1};   & \node {1}; \\
    \node    {12};  & \node     {12};  & \node {1}; \\
    \node    {1};   & \node     {123}; & \node {1}; \\
  };
  
\draw [<->,red,thick] (a.center) -- (b.center) node [above,midway] {1cm};

\end{tikzpicture}
```

In the tikz manual I see that column sep = {spacing list}

But when I add distances to my spacing list it doesn't seem to affect the distances between the columns in my matrix. All I want to do is specify distances between in the nodes in my matrix in a column wise or row wise manner.

Comment: I don't understand what you want to achieve. Using `column sep=1cm` sets the distance between the nodes to 1cm. If the nodes have different widths, the distance between the longest width in each column is used. Use `row sep` to set the distance between the rows.

Comment: Adding to my comment, both options, `column sep` and `row sep` can take a so-called "spacing list" which may contain more than one distance as well as one key word. The sevaral distances are just summed up. The keyword may be `between origins` and `between borders` and tells Ti*k*Z to use the origin or the borders of the neighboring cells to set the distance. If I take your example, it works just as expected.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure that I really understand what you want to achieve, but maybe the following can help you:

The Ti*k*Z manual explains that there exist the options `column sep` and `row sep` which you can use to set the column distance and the row distance between matrix nodes respectively.

Both options take a so-called "spacing list". This spacing list may just contain one single value (a distance), which should be enough in most cases to set the relevant distance.

However, if more than one value are given in this list and they are distances, all these distances will be added together. Futhermore the last value of this list may be `between origins` or `between borders` which will set the distance either between the centers of the respective nodes or between the borders, the latter being the default.

So, the following may explain how the addition of multiple distances given to the options works:

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \matrix [draw, column sep={1cm, 5pt}, row sep={0.5cm}, nodes=draw]
  {
    \node (a) {123}; & \node     {1};   & \node {1}; \\
    \node (c) {12};  & \node     {12};  & \node {1}; \\
    \node     {1};   & \node (b) {123}; & \node {1}; \\
  };

\draw [cyan] (a.north -| b.west) -- (b.north west);

\draw [<->, red, thick] (a.east) -- ++({1cm+5pt},0) node [above, midway, font=\tiny] {1cm + 5pt};

\draw [<->, red, thick] (b.east) -- ++({1cm+5pt},0) node [above, midway, font=\tiny] {1cm + 5pt};

\draw [<->, red, thick] (a.south) -- ++(0,-0.5cm) node [right, midway, font=\tiny] {0.5cm};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

As explained in comments and other answers, the list you're given to `column sep` will just get added to get the final column sep.

If you want a specific coumn sep for every column you will need to set `column sep` for each column or use the optional argment for `&` (`\pgfmatrixnextcell`) whose value gets added to the default `column sep`. So, with an unchanged `column sep=0pt` you could do

```
\matrix[
  draw,
  column sep={between origins},
  nodes=draw] {
    \node(a) {123}; &[1cm] \node (b) {1};   &[4cm] \node {1}; \\
    \node    {12};  &      \node     {12};  &      \node {1}; \\
    \node    {1};   &      \node     {123}; &      \node {1}; \\
  };
```

but I believe a key like `column separations bo` as used below is much more useful (`bo` = between origins). Similar keys can defined for `between borders` and the rows.

The extra grouping of `##1` makes sure you can use, say, `{min(1cm,width("Test"))},5cm}` as an argument and the `,` of the `min` function doesn't trip up the inner workings. However, you can't use a another “spacing list” for each column but you can just use `+` instead of `,` to add multiples values together.

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\tikzset{
  column separations bo/.style={
    /utils/exec=\def\pgfmathcounter{0},
    /utils/temp/.style={
      /utils/exec=\edef\pgfmathcounter{\pgfinteval{\pgfmathcounter+1}},
      /tikz/column \pgfmathcounter/.append style={column sep={{##1},between origins}}},
    /utils/temp/.list={#1}}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix[
  draw,
  column separations bo={1cm,4cm},
  nodes=draw] {
    \node(a) {123}; & \node (b) {1};   & \node {1}; \\
    \node    {12};  & \node     {12};  & \node {1}; \\
    \node    {1};   & \node     {123}; & \node {1}; \\
  };
\path [<->,red,thick,above] (a.center) edge node {1cm} ++(right:1cm)
                            (b.center) edge node {4cm} ++(right:4cm);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Comment: Something like `… = {1 = 1cm, 2 = 4cm}` where `1` stands for column 1 and so on is possible, too.